# HTML to plain text email on web-based email form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I need turn HTML email into a plain text email.

Currently, my email go out as HTML and I get this message in Horde HTML client:

*This message part contains HTML data, but inline HTML display is disabled.
View HTML data in new window.
Convert HTML data to plain text and view in new window.*

I used third-party web-based email editor which allows for all sort of customized codes at the back-end of the email message body.

I cannot directly delete any specific lines, and therefore a separate code will be required for any removal or modification.

```html
      <div id="tab-mailContent" class="tab-pane active">
           <fieldset id="mail-content-options">
             <table class="form-table">
               <tbody><tr>
                 <td class="form-inline">
                   <label for="mail_title" class=" required">Title</label>
                   <input id="mail_title" name="mail[title]" value="MBS1" type="text">
                 </td>
                          <input id="mail_distributorMessageId" name="mail[distributorMessageId]" type="hidden">
    
                 <td class="form-inline">
                   <label for="mail_promotion" class=" required">Promotion</label>
                   <select id="mail_promotion" name="mail[promotion]" class="w140"><option value=""></option><option value="1">Employee Discount</option></select>
                 </td>
                 <td class="form-inline">
                  <input value="Upload images" class="btn clicked-border" id="upload_images_btn" type="button">
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </tbody></table>
           </fieldset>
    <div>
    <textarea id="mail_body" name="mail[body]" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">Hello! We truly appreciate your business today and look forward to serving you again in 2 weeks or sooner. </textarea>
```

Comment: Do you want something like this link:-https://ctrlq.org/code/19813-convert-html-to-text

Comment: I need some more details on its application. Its not working with copy pasting. Perhaps, I am not applying it correctly.